# Windows 10 Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP), cannot open virtual port

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, serial-port, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

After upgrading our Windows 10 PCs (to 1803 + 1809), it is not possible to connect to/open the (Bluetooth) virtual serial ports anymore.

We are using Bluetooth Barcode-Readers, which are connected via Bluetooth to virtual COM-Ports. Older versions of Windows (7/8/8.1), does not have this problem.

Pairing works, virtual COM-Ports are also created. It is just not possible to connect to. (**Cannot open COM-Port**)

We also tried BlueSoleil and Toshiba Bluetooth Stack.
But with no success. Bluetooth SPP does not work anymore.

Does anyone has an idea to solve this problem?